# Finding points inside of a box

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I have a set of points in 3D that define a large, complex object. These points are rendered in OpenGL for an Android app that I am programming.

In this app, the user translates the center of the box to a point on this object. When the box is locked onto a point, the box can be stretched/squeezed (in either the X,Y, or Z direction) and rotated along the X,Y, and Z axis, with the point of rotation being the point on the object.

The user then presses a button, and all the points from the object that lie inside of the box are supposed to be found and saved. This is where I have am having difficulty.

Without rotation, my problem is easy. I just iterated through all my points and checked whether the point on my current iteration fell within this range (pseudocode is below):

`if (pointX <= pointOnObjectX + width/2 and pointX >= pointOnObjectX - width/2 and pointY <= pointOnObjectY + length/2 and pointY >= pointOnObjectY - length/2 
and pointZ <= pointOnObjectZ + height/2 and pointZ >= pointOnObjectZ - height/2)`

`Save Point`

Now obviously, when the user rotates the box, this does not work. Given my limited knowledge of Linear Algebra, does anyone have any idea on how I can make my calculation to see which points are inside my rotated box? Here is some data that I have:

1. All the points of my object
2. The center of the box
3. The length/width/height of the box
4. Rotation matrix for my box

Comment: Instead of applying the rotation to the box, you could apply the opposite rotation to the points and check if their image points are in the initial box. This is equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm.